# Sharepoint SPFieldType information

Tags: sharepoint-2007, rendering, fieldtype

I was working on an assignement which consists of
rendering the following field types in sharepoint:

1. Lookup
2. MaxItems
3. MultiChoice
4. Choice
5. ModStat
6. GridChoice

I have managed to render the following field types:

1. Lookup
2. MultiChoice
3. Choice

But i don't know anything about the other three.
What they are, how they look like?
I have searched in MSDN but i didn't find
the help needed.

Does anyone have any information?
Is there any reference that i can refer to?
I appreciate any code, link, advice..

**Edit:**
I figured out two of the remaining types, but i still have "MaxItems".
Can any one help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK finally i managed to solve my problems:

1. To render the type ModStat we use a dropdown of available statuses.
2. To render the type GridChoice we use a RatingScaleField
3. I didn't manage to get a reference for the MaxItems field in sharepoint,
   but i think it can be rendered using a numeric text box.

Comment: for a yes/no field in sharepoint what is the corresponding SPFieldType for this kind of field ?

Comment: For yes/no the corresponding field type is SPFieldType.Boolean.